# Can I have "git stash" to automatically include untracked files by default?

Tags: git, git-stash

Well, as the title says, is there an option I can set in git, that will make it automatically include untracked files when I execute `git stash`, so I don't have to remember the `-u` option.

Alternately, after I created a stash, and I discover that I forgot to include untracked files, can I amend those to the stash?

Comment: for the second question you can just pop the stash and create it again

Comment: I know about the pop/stash (that's what I do currently), but when working with Visual Studio on Windows, this pop/stash often involves reloading the project twice (once for pop, once for stash), with some problems involved, e.g. locked files, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I failed to find a configuration option to do this in the `git-config` manual page (`$ man git-config`, or `$ git config --help`, or [read it online](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)), but you can get away easily using an alias:

```
$ git config alias.stashall 'stash -u'
$ git stashall
```

Comment: I managed to change my routing slightly using an alias as suggested, and it seems to work fine for me.